# How can I set a Variable in For-Loop in a batchscript

Tags: for-loop, setlocale, batch-file

I am looking for an solution for a trivial problem, i can't get solved. Please help me with that.
My plan is to read 2 files. one of them is an folder structur the other is a user list.
if the folder word is not found in the user list the (e.g. Profile) folder gets deleted.
I am still testing so please do not refere yet to the missing delete in my code.
here is what i've got yet:

---

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 >nul

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cls

echo --- working ---

for /f "delims=," %%x in (Profile.txt) do (
    set counter = 0
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (ADMPReport.csv) do (
        IF "%%x"=="%%b" (
            echo %%x & echo %%b
            REM IF User is found counter gets 1
            set counter = 1
            echo %counter%
            pause
        ) 
    )
    echo %counter%
    REM if no user found Counter = 0
    if %counter% == "0" echo %%x 
        REM ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >NUL
)

echo ---- done ----
ENDLOCAL

ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >NUL
```

---

My Problem here is that the counter stays at 1 ...

Any Help would be perfect.
Best,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

First, initialize your counter variable outside the for loop. 
Second, you're setting counter to 1 on every iteration...not adding to it. To do this in dos batch you must use set /a. It should look like this:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 >nul

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cls

echo --- working ---

set counter=0
for /f "delims=," %%x in (Profile.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (ADMPReport.csv) do (
        IF "%%x"=="%%b" (
            echo %%x & echo %%b
            REM IF User is found counter gets 1
            set /a counter=%counter%+1
            echo %counter%
            pause
        ) 
    )
    echo %counter%
    REM if no user found Counter = 0
    if %counter% == "0" echo %%x 
        REM ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >NUL
)

echo ---- done ----
ENDLOCAL

ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >NUL
```

Comment: Hi, No that didn`t help yet. 2 Things to mention here: i dont need the couter to get bigger than 1, there will never be more that 1 match. second i need to set counter to 0 in outer loop. i tried now to set the younter twice, initialize before loop, and set 0 again in outer loop. heres my new code: